# how to Adding pagination on template page wordpress

Tags: pagination

Below is my code with the template. I have included pagination but not working.

```
<?php     
/*
Template Name: bydate
*/

?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area clear">   
        <main id="main" class="site-main clear">
            <div id="recent-content" class="content-list">
                <?php 
                $args = array(
                    'posts_per_page' => 2,
                    'orderby' => 'endon',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'meta_type' => 'DATE',
                    'meta_key' => 'endon',
                );
                $news = new WP_Query($args); 
                ?>

                <?php
                if ( have_posts() ) :       
                /* Start the Loop */
                while ($news->have_posts()) : $news->the_post();
                    get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'list');
                endwhile;
                else :
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
                endif; 
                ?>

            </div><!-- #recent-content -->      
        </main><!-- .site-main -->

        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/pagination', '' ); ?>

    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

thank's

Answer (score 0):

`get_template_part( 'template-parts/pagination', '' );` is merely including the `template-parts/pagination.php` file from your theme. If you don't have that file then nothing will happen.

The correct way to add pagination is either the [`paginate_links()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/) function, which will output links for each page number (see that link for the options for customising the output):

```
<?php echo paginate_links(); ?>
```

Or you could just output 'next page' and 'previous page' links with [`posts_nav_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/posts_nav_link/):

```
<?php echo posts_nav_link(); ?>
```

If you want more control over where the next and previous links appear, you can output them separately with [`previous_post_link()][3]` and [`next_post_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/next_posts_link/).

```
<?php previous_post_link(); ?>
<?php next_post_link(); ?>
```